# python - How to transform key-value pairs in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, key-value

I received this dataset which contains real estate data in key-value pairs in a .csv format.

If I drop the first line, I can load it with Pandas and get a dataframe like so:

|  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id 1 | [{'key'": '"floor'" | '"value'": '"2. Floor'"} | {'"key'": '"available_date'" | "value'": '"nach Vereinbarung'"} |
| id 2 | [{'key'": '"floor'" | '"value'": '"1. Floor'"} | {'"key'": '"living_space'" | "value'": 81.0} |
| id 3 | [{'key'": '"living_space'" | '"value'": 240.0} | {'"key'": '"construction_year'" | '"value'": 2012} |
| id 4 | [{'key'": '"living_space'" | '"value'": 280.0} | {'"key'": '"construction_year'" | '"value'": 1851} |

However, I don't know how to work with key-value pairs in Python, so I wanted to transform this data into a Pandas dataframe, with the "keys" as the headers and their respective values in each row, like so:

| id | floor | available_date | living_space | construction_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id 1 | 2. Floor |  | nach Vereinbarung |  |
| id 2 | 1. Floor | 81 |  |  |
| id 3 |  | 240.0 |  | 2012 |
| id 4 |  | 280.0 |  | 1851 |

I have found many instructions on how to transform a Pandas dataframe into key-value pairs, but not the other way around...

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

The content of my data looks like this:

```
print(df.head(10))
           [{'key'": '"floor'"   '"value'": '"3. Stock'"}        {'"key'": '"living_space'"    '"value'": 50.0}      {'"key'": '"available_date'"  ... Unnamed: 49 Unnamed: 50 Unnamed: 51 Unnamed: 52 Unnamed: 53
0          [{'key'": '"floor'"   '"value'": '"2. Stock'"}        {'"key'": '"living_space'"   '"value'": 113.0}   {'"key'": '"construction_year'"  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
1          [{'key'": '"floor'"   '"value'": '"1. Stock'"}        {'"key'": '"living_space'"    '"value'": 52.0}   {'"key'": '"construction_year'"  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
..                         ...                        ...                               ...                 ...                               ...  ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...
8   [{'key'": '"living_space'"          '"value'": 240.0}   {'"key'": '"construction_year'"    '"value'": 2012}      {'"key'": '"available_date'"  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN
9   [{'key'": '"living_space'"          '"value'": 280.0}   {'"key'": '"construction_year'"    '"value'": 1851}      {'"key'": '"available_date'"  ...         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN

[10 rows x 54 columns]
```

**UPDATE**

The contents of the .csv looks like the following (for the 2 first observations):

> 1,"[{'key'"": '""floor'"""," '""value'"": '""3. Stock'""}","
> {'""key'"": '""living_space'"""," '""value'"": 50.0}"," {'""key'"":
> '""available_date'"""," '""value'"": '""01.04.2022'""}"," {'""key'"":
> '""useful_area'"""," '""value'"": 60.0}"," {'""key'"":
> '""pets_allowed'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"":
> '""child_friendly'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"":
> '""balcony'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"":
> '""parking_outdoor'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"":
> '""lift'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"": '""cable_tv'""","
> '""value'"": true}]""","[{'date'"": '""2022-02-25'""","
> '""price_amount'"": 1550}]"""
>
> 2,"[{'key'"": '""floor'"""," '""value'"": '""2. Stock'""}","
> {'""key'"": '""living_space'"""," '""value'"": 113.0}"," {'""key'"":
> '""construction_year'"""," '""value'"": 2022}"," {'""key'"":
> '""available_date'"""," '""value'"": '""01.04.2022'""}"," {'""key'"":
> '""wheelchair_accessible'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"":
> '""child_friendly'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"":
> '""balcony'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"":
> '""parking_indoor'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"":
> '""lift'"""," '""value'"": true}]""","[{'date'"": '""2022-02-27'""","
> '""price_amount'"": 2990}]"""

The data was scrapped from real estate online marketplaces it seems.
I think is also relevant to state that each observation has a different number of features.

Comment: Can you show us your data in terms of Python code/objects?

Comment: How are you receiving that data... are you sure you don't have a JSON file or something... or are you actually getting a really mucked up DF?

Comment: Your original columns don't have names? Can you provide the constructor for your dataframe? `df.to_dict()`

Comment: you have [ at the first column but where is the ] ?

Comment: I received the data as a .csv file. I have just realized that if I remove the headers completely, I can load the csv with Pandas (I was getting an error: "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 2, saw 75"). So now I have the csv as a DataFrame, so all I need to understand is how to transform the data in a table with the keys as headers like in the second table.

Comment: looks like it is a `json` file even if it has `csv` extension because it does not looks like csv content. could you provide the content of csv file you have received?

Comment: @GreyMurav I have updated the question with a print of the data.
And thank you all for the interaction.

Comment: You have written the following: `I received the data as a .csv file.` Could you provide content of that file or at least a part of it? I believe the issue is in the conversion of the file to dataframe.

Comment: @GreyMurav is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Possible solution is the following:**

**file 'data.csv' content**

```
1,"[{'key'"": '""floor'"""," '""value'"": '""3. Stock'""}"," {'""key'"": '""living_space'"""," '""value'"": 50.0}"," {'""key'"": '""available_date'"""," '""value'"": '""01.04.2022'""}"," {'""key'"": '""useful_area'"""," '""value'"": 60.0}"," {'""key'"": '""pets_allowed'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"": '""child_friendly'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"": '""balcony'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"": '""parking_outdoor'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"": '""lift'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"": '""cable_tv'"""," '""value'"": true}]""","[{'date'"": '""2022-02-25'"""," '""price_amount'"": 1550}]"""
2,"[{'key'"": '""floor'"""," '""value'"": '""2. Stock'""}"," {'""key'"": '""living_space'"""," '""value'"": 113.0}"," {'""key'"": '""construction_year'"""," '""value'"": 2022}"," {'""key'"": '""available_date'"""," '""value'"": '""01.04.2022'""}"," {'""key'"": '""wheelchair_accessible'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"": '""child_friendly'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"": '""balcony'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"": '""parking_indoor'"""," '""value'"": true}"," {'""key'"": '""lift'"""," '""value'"": true}]""","[{'date'"": '""2022-02-27'"""," '""price_amount'"": 2990}]"""
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# read data from csv file
with open("data.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    data = file.read().replace('"', '').replace("'", '"').replace("[", '').replace("]", '').splitlines()

# convert string to list
data_dict = [json.loads("[" + d + "]") for d in data]

data_all = []

for list_item in data_dict:
    data_prepared = {}
    for idx, item in enumerate(list_item):
        if idx == 0:
            data_prepared["id"] = item
        else:
            if 'key' in item:
                data_prepared[item['key']] = item['value']
            else:
                data_prepared.update(item)
    data_all.append(data_prepared)

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data_all)
df = df.fillna("-")
df = df.replace(True, 'Yes')
df = df.replace(False, 'No')
df
```

Returns

[image]